# Http method GET shows error when using jersey

Tags: java, rest, servlets, jersey

I am following a tutorial to learn REST api. Below is my code that has GET annotation and use Weblogic server to deploy my application. For some reason it is showing the following error:

```
HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
```

Sample.java

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/v1")
public class V1_status {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String returnTitle(){
        return "<p> Yess </p>";
    }
}
```

web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>com.glasschecker.rest</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.glasschecker.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  </web-app>
```

This is the tutorial:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4DY46f-LZ0M&list=PLu47tUtKqNlwfR-
>   nqjiWUaIWOYEi9FyW0&index=2

I use the following URL http://localhost:7001/com.glasschecker.rest/api/v1 the URL pattern is added to the Servlet.

When I try to access http://localhost:7001/com.glasschecker.rest it shows the index.html file properly (first file in my web.xml). I am sure something in my file.

**NOTE the java class is inside this package:**

**com.glasschecker.rest.status**

This is the error i am getting:

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: weblogic.management.DeploymentException: [HTTP:101170]The servlet org.foo.rest.MyApplication is referenced in servlet-mapping /api but not defined in web.xml.
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:237)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:232)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: weblogic.management.DeploymentException: [HTTP:101170]The servlet org.foo.rest.MyApplication is referenced in servlet-mapping /api but not defined in web.xml.
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.verifyServletMappings(WebAppServletContext.java:1566)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3066)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1830)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:875)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
```

Comment: You haven't annotated your your class with @Path

Comment: Do you have a `Application` subclass annotated with `@ApplicationPath`? Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: I assume na error appears on startup? if it does this means your getting 404 (not found) because the app did not properly deploy.

Comment: Can you post this class: org.foo.rest.MyApplication?

Answer (score 3):

Here is complete working code :

```
@Path("/ws")
public class V1_status {

@GET
@Path("/title") //this one is optional
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String returnTitle(){
return "<p> Yess </p>";
}

}
```

1. use anotation [@Path("path_name_here")](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) in order to declare a rest path to a ressource.
2. access your endpoint in the uri : http://localhost:8080/ws/title  ( assuming base server path is : http://localhost:8080)
3. check weblogic installation [jax-rs-2.0.war](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/RESTF/use-jersey20-ri.htm#RESTF296)
4. check that your Rest webservice Resource class is in package   (declared with `com.sun.jersey.config.property.package`)

Comment: Thanks jeorfevr but still i am facing the same issue

Comment: have you got Select the jax-rs-2.0.war file installed in weblogic

Comment: jax-rs-2.0 is found inside the \wlserver\common\deployable-libraries so i hope it is installed.

Comment: can  you check in your admin console that it's installed ?  fallow Registering the Jersey 2.5.1 https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/RESTF/use-jersey20-ri.htm#RESTF299

Comment: I have installed jax via administration console but still same problem.Am i missing still something.

Comment: please share web.xml in order to find problem's root.

Comment: can you try  : to call  http://localhost:7001/api/v1 please ? since your not declaring url pattern you assume to declare

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111034/discussion-between-jeorfevre-and-anbu-selvan).

Comment: you mean the url pattern is wrong.Still i tried your way same result

Answer (score 1):

You defined `/v1` path but request `/api/v1`.
try:

```
@Path("/api")
public class V1_status {
    @Path("v1")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String returnTitle(){
        return "<p> Yess </p>";
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks now i am getting Not Found message.I use the following url:-

     http://localhost:7001/com.glasschecker.rest/api/v1/status

Comment: Not found what? All message, please.

Comment: Your request has to be /api/v1 without status

Comment: When i access the path even without status it shows a page with the messaga as Not Found.

Comment: Why do you use path localhost:7001/com.glasschecker.rest/api/v1/status, not  localhost:7001/api/v1?

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your class with @Path annotation as that is required by JAX-RS runtime to treat your class as a resource.

Comment: Thanks Tirath still same problem

Answer (score 0):

The property "com.sun.jersey.config.property.package" just needs to be set as the package that contains the web service classes.

In your case is the "V1_status" class package: "com.glasschecker.rest.status"

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>com.glasschecker.rest.status</param-value>
</init-param>
```

As specified in [Jersey ServletContainer documentation](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.7/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/servlet/ServletContainer.html)

```
if the initialization parameter "com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass" is not present and a initialization parameter "com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages" is present a new instance of PackagesResourceConfig is created. The initialization parameter "com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages" MUST be set to provide one or more package names.
```

PackagesResourceConfig dynamically searches for root resource and provider classes. In this case "V1_status" is your root resource.

Comment: I think this might fix the issue. I saw comments similar to this on the youtube video to change the <param-value> for <init-param>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</init-param>. Author set the  <param-value>  with <display-name> which is not correct if your service class is in a different package.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete `web.xml` file or clear all servlet and servlet mapping things.
2. There should be an `ApplicationConfig` class that extends `Application`. Annotate `ApplicationPath('/')` or however you want.

Here is an example `ApplicationConfig` class

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("/")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        addRestResourceClasses(resources);
        return resources;
    }

    /**
     * Do not modify addRestResourceClasses() method.
     * It is automatically populated with
     * all resources defined in the project.
     * If required, comment out calling this method in getClasses().
     */
    private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        resources.add(com.testrest.StuffResource.class);
    }

}
```